# Modern Pages Layout Size

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, modern-pages

Is there anyway to change the layout of the modern pages? As currently my page will only allow to have items half way of the page. The other half of the page is a giant white space. See the pic for reference  https://i.stack.imgur.com/25E7m.png

Is there anyway to reduce or remove the white space? Or make the make webparts appear on the right hand side?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are option to change your modern page layout. You choose two column or three column layout and then move your content to the right of the page. Once you edit the page and click on the red box marked layout option. you can see as below attached image.

[image]

Try to use the Different Layout options and add webparts.

Comment: Hi, I have tried using the columns in the layout options. However no matter what layout I choose the white space is still appearing on the right hand side. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think all the different webparts OOTB has defined with min-width and Max width. if you want to override the css, then you have to inject the Custom Css in your Modern page which is not good suggestion.but still you want to do the then install this app https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor and add into your page and write your custom css